Failed to extract key generated by google's certtostore golang library in Windows
Here is the sample golang code using google's certtostore library which does the following -

Generates the Keypair.
Save the signed certificate having the public key generated in step 1 in Windows Certificate Store.
Attempts to fetch Certificate and Private Key

Here is the sample code -
Generation of Keypair
store, err := certtostore.OpenWinCertStoreCurrentUser(
certtostore.ProviderMSSoftware, "", nil, nil, false)
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println(err)
} else {
   options := certtostore.GenerateOpts{Algorithm: algo, Size: size}
   signer, err := store.Generate(options)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
   }
   store.Close()
   return signer
}

if store != nil {
   store.Close()
}
return nil


Saving certificate in Windows Certificate Store
store, err := certtostore.OpenWinCertStoreCurrentUser(
certtostore.ProviderMSSoftware, "", issuers, nil, false)
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println(err)
} else {
   storeErr := store.StoreWithDisposition(cert, intermediate, windows.CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING)
   if storeErr != nil {
      fmt.Println(storeErr)
   }
}

if store != nil {
   store.Close()
}

Fetch Certificate and Key
store, err := certtostore.OpenWinCertStoreCurrentUser(
certtostore.ProviderMSSoftware, "", issuers, nil, false)
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println(err)

   if store != nil {
      store.Close()
   }

   return nil, nil
} else {
   crt, context, err1 := store.CertWithContext()
   if err1 != nil {
      fmt.Println(err1)
      if store != nil {
         store.Close()
      }
      return nil, nil
   } else {
      key, err2 := store.CertKey(context)
      fmt.Println("key container id " + key.Container)
      fmt.Println("legacy key container id " + key.LegacyContainer)
      if err2 != nil {
         fmt.Println(err2)
         if store != nil {
            store.Close()
         }
         return nil, nil
      } else {
         fmt.Println(key)
      }
      if store != nil {
         store.Close()
      }
      return crt, key
   }
}

While fetching key using store.CertKey(context) I get following error -
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x18 pc=0x7ff63fb36552]

The function that fails is syscall.Syscall6 and the failed stack is -
syscall.Syscall6(p.Addr(), uintptr(len(a)), a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5])

cryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey.Call

store.CertKey(context)

